# Why are the sets $G_{\alpha}$ open relative to $X$ in the given proof?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I was looking over Theorem 2.33 from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, and I was wondering why the sets $G_{\alpha}$ are open relative to $X$? I thought that by definition, the sets $G_{\alpha}$ should be open in $X$. I've provided Theorem 2.30 and the proof of Theorem 2.33 below.

As reference: **Theorem 2.30** Suppose $Y \subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if $E = Y \cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

> **Theorem 2.33** Suppose $K \subset Y \subset X$. Then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

> **Proof** Suppose $K$ is compact relative to $X$, and let $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection of sets, open relative to $Y$, such that $$K \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} V_{\alpha} \tag{22}$$ By theorem 2.30, there are sets $G_{\alpha}$, open relative to $X$, such that $V_{\alpha} = Y \cap G_{\alpha}$, for all $\alpha$; and since $K$ is compact relative to $X$, we have $$K \subset G_{\alpha_{1}} \cup \cdots \cup G_{\alpha_{n}}\tag{23}$$ for some choice of finitely many indices $\alpha_{1}, \cdots ,\alpha_{n}$. Since $K \subset Y$, $(22)$ implies $$K \subset V_{\alpha_{1}} \cup \cdots \cup V_{a_{n}}$$ This proves that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

Comment: The sets $G_\alpha$ are open in $X$ because we choose them to be open in $X$. That such sets exist is a consequence of **Theorem 2.30** and the fact that the sets $V_\alpha$ are assumed to be open in $Y$, and since they exist, we can choose them.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: So in this case, $G_{\alpha}$ is open in $X$ because it is open relative to $X$?

Comment: I use *open in* $X$ and *open relative to* $X$ pretty much synonymously. What, exactly, is Rudin’s definition of *open relative to* some set?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Sorry, yes open in $X$ and open relative to $X$ are pretty much synonymous. I think what I meant to ask is why $G_{\alpha}$ is not considered to be just an open set? So that $V_{\alpha} = Y \cap G_{\alpha}$, which means that $V_{\alpha}$ is open relative to $Y$.

Comment: Assuming that $X$ is the ambient space in which all of this is taking place, $G_\alpha$ **is** just an open set. However, the result still holds if the ambient space is some larger space $Z$, with $K\subseteq Y\subseteq X\subseteq Z$, and then the sets $G_\alpha$, while open as subsets of $X$, need be open in the whole space $Z$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: You’re welcome.